# 401 Unauthorized when trying to publish artifacts to sonatype repository with new url with snapshots as well as release

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, nexus, kotlin-multiplatform, sonatype

This is the content of my build.gradle.kts file

```
import org.gradle.api.publish.maven.MavenPublication
import org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar
import java.util.*

plugins {
    id("maven-publish")
    id("signing")
}

// Stub secrets to let the project sync and build without the publication values set up
ext["signing.keyId"] = null
ext["signing.password"] = null
ext["signing.secretKeyRingFile"] = null
ext["ossrhUsername"] = null
ext["ossrhPassword"] = null

// Grabbing secrets from local.properties file or from environment variables, which could be used on CI
val secretPropsFile = project.rootProject.file("local.properties")
if (secretPropsFile.exists()) {
    secretPropsFile.reader().use {
        Properties().apply { load(it) }
    }.onEach { (name, value) ->
        ext[name.toString()] = value
    }
} else {
    ext["signing.keyId"] = System.getenv("SIGNING_KEY_ID")
    ext["signing.password"] = System.getenv("SIGNING_PASSWORD")
    ext["signing.secretKeyRingFile"] = System.getenv("SIGNING_SECRET_KEY_RING_FILE")
    ext["ossrhUsername"] = System.getenv("OSSRH_USERNAME")
    ext["ossrhPassword"] = System.getenv("OSSRH_PASSWORD")
}

val javadocJar by tasks.registering(Jar::class) {
    archiveClassifier.set("javadoc")
}

fun getExtraString(name: String) = ext[name]?.toString()

publishing {
// Configure maven central repository
    repositories {
        maven {
            isAllowInsecureProtocol = true
            name = "sonatype"
            var repositoryUrl = ""
            repositoryUrl = if (version.toString().endsWith("SNAPSHOT")) {
                "https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
            } else {
                "https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/"
            }

            url = uri(repositoryUrl)
            credentials {
                username = getExtraString("ossrhUsername")
                password = getExtraString("ossrhPassword")
            }
        }
    }

// Configure all publications
    publications.withType<MavenPublication> {
        // Stub javadoc.jar artifact
        artifact(javadocJar.get())

        // Provide artifacts information requited by Maven Central
        pom {
            name.set("Candlesticks Chart library")
            description.set("Candlesticks Chart Library for Kotlin Multiplatform to draw candle chart.")
            url.set("https://github.com/yashctn88/candlestickschartkmm")

            licenses {
                license {
                    name.set("MIT")
                    url.set("https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT")
                }
            }
            developers {
                developer {
                    id.set("yashctn88")
                    name.set("Yash Kalariya")
                    email.set("yash@bcsnctn.onmicrosoft.com")
                }
            }
            scm {
                url.set("https://github.com/yashctn88/candlestickschartkmm/tree/main")
            }
        }
    }
}

signing {
    if (getExtraString("signing.keyId") != null) {
        sign(publishing.publications)
    }
}

val signingTasks = tasks.withType()
tasks.withType().configureEach {
    mustRunAfter(signingTasks)
}
```

I have double verified the credentials and namespace and gpg keys. I am able to push with local host setup on the nexus repository manger local instance but same when i change the url and the username and token that i have obtained from the central.sonatype.org its failing with the 401 unauthorised code

Tried multiple times with this setup with local host setting nexus repo manager upload is working but when i set it to live server url its failing.